# Is it possible to get Twitter trends using Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, api, twitter, zend-framework2

I am using Zend Framework 2 and am successfully using their `ZendService/Twitter/Twitter.php` class. I am able to use this service to search for tweets, hashtags, and so on.

Is it possible to use this class to get the latest trends on Twitter? I see that the Twitter API offers `trends/place`, but ZF2 does not seem to offer the functionality to access any `trends/place` information.

The valid method types in `Twitter.php` are listed as:

```
protected $methodTypes = array(
    'account',
    'application',
    'blocks',
    'directmessages',
    'favorites',
    'friendships',
    'search',
    'statuses',
    'users',
);
```

`trends` is not one of the valid method types. Does this mean that `trends` cannot be retrieved by using this service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of research, I don't believe that ZF2's Twitter service offers to ability to retrieve the `trends/place` feed from Twitter.

Therefore I am using the TwitterAPIExchange class in [J7mbo/twitter-api-php](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php) instead (I am not affiliated with this project). Using this class, I am successfully able to retrieve the `trends/place` feed.